# Reorganization of matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix A=MxN in Matlab, where M=23 and N=780.

I want to take all the 23 rows and 15 columns per time (780/15= 52 times) and append it each time.

I want to get a matrix B=GxT, where G is 23*52 and T is 15.

I'm trying to use reshape, whitout any good result.

COuld you suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 3):

How about using `reshape` and `permute`:

```
B = reshape(permute(reshape(A, [23,15,52]), [1 3 2]), [23*52 15]);
```

Best,

Comment: @gnovice Thanks, I hadn't understood this part of the question but it makes sense. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It works fine! thank you. Just a bracket missing to close permute.

Comment: Ok, I've corrected my answer. Don't forget to close the question by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) ([as suggested by Ratbert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438545/52738)) is likely going to be the fastest, but for completeness you can also do this by collecting submatrices in a cell array using [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and rebuilding the matrix using [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html):

```
B = mat2cell(A, 23, repmat(15, [1 52]));
B = vertcat(B{:});
```

Comment: Nice answer! I wouldn't have thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.  Do you have the code that you tried?  I think I get what you are trying to do, so I'll take a stab at creating a code here.

```
%Initialize matrix A here with whatever numbers you have.
ResultMat = zeros((23*52),15); TempColsMat = zeros(1,15);
for row = 1 : 23
    k = 0;
    for col = 1 : 52
        TempColsMat = A(row,(k : (k + 15)));
        ResultMat = (TempColsMat(:,:),:);
        k = k + 15;
    end
end
```

It took me a while to figure it out because I don't have MATLAB in front of me, but I think this code should work.  Good luck with your project!